# What does "less so" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

I was reading an answer on a forum and didn't understand what "less so" means. Here's the context

> "Yeah, that combo is my work daily driver right now, in an MF108 case. It's the most tactile thing ever and amazingly enough it's not quite as loud as some other switch/keycap/case combinations. It's not quiet, not by any stretch, but **less so** than Outemu Blues being pounded on at the desk next to me."

I think that by using “less so” he means that his combo  is quieter than Outemu Blues. Am I right?.

Comment: I believe your interpretation of the *intended* meaning is correct, but the actual meaning as phrased is that his combo is "less quiet" than the Outemu blues. The writer should probably have said **"less loud"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Less so*** is a “contextual comparative”
 and it modifies another adjective  indicating a lesser degree of the quality in question.

In your context it refers to the adjective “quiet”.